# Manual account sharing with all users

Tags: accountshare

my Sharing Settings for Account is private.
However I want to have some Accounts shared to everybody.
I could create one record of AccountShare for each user but I know that's not the best solution:
1 - a new user is created and those records are not shared with them;
2 - high number of records of AccountShare

I thought on a queue containing all users and then share that account with that queue. Than I've saw that Queues do not allot Account as an object option. So I guess I cant share with a queue either.

So is there an easier way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution for this would be to use a **criteria-based Sharing Rule** on the Account object.

You can create an Account field that is used to flag the accounts you want to share with everyone (might be a simple checkbox or maybe a picklist if you want something more robust and have a use-case for it). Then set "Share with" as the standard public group "All Internal Users". As new users are created, they will automatically become part of this standard group and gain access to the Accounts you've specified in your criteria.

Comment: thanks for your reply! Didnt use that feature before

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with a basic sharing rule.

1. Go to Sharing Settings
2. Scroll to "Account Sharing Rules"
3. For Rule Type, select Based on Criteria.
4. Define your criteria
5. Sharing with "Public Groups" > "All Internal Users"

Comment: Perfect thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some have suggested creating a custom field with Sharing Rules, but if this is truly manual, you also have the option of using the standard Sharing button and share with the Public Group called "All Internal Users"

[image: manual sharing]

Pro- no additional config/automation setup

Con- doesn't provide the ability to report on which Accounts you've shared with all users

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Where do I find that Share button?

Comment: It is available on any object that has its visibility level set below Public Read/Write, and can be added to the Page Layout as a standard action, or now with Dynamic Actions in the Lightning App Builder